# Shiny: Generating a selectInput from a list of lists goes directly to the deepest layer

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a heavily nested list (6 layers) as the basis to generate a series of drop down menus.   However when passing the nested list through the selectInput function the deepest layer is what the selection is made out of. Below is a simple app to reproduce the issue I am encountering.

```
    library(shiny)

    problemList <- list(
      deeperList = list (
        element1 = 1,
        element2 = 2
      ),
      deeperList2 = list (
        element3 = 3,
        element4 = 4
      )
    )

    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput(inputId = "dropDownMenu", label = "Drop Down Menu", choices = problemList)
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {}

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Image showing what is generated by the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxS8b.png)

I am trying to make the user choose between deeperList and deeperList2 in the first drop down menu. If they choose deeperList then another dropdown menu will be generated allowing the user to choose between element1 and element2, but if they choose deeperList2 then another dropdown menu will be generated allowing the user to choose between element3 and element4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two ways of doing this.

1. Create the second dropdown list with `renderUI`. By doing so, you can make the choices of the second dropdown menu dependend on the choice of the first dropdown menu. See the "Creating Controls On the Fly With renderUI" sections from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html#creating-controls-on-the-fly-with-renderui).
2. Use `updateSelectInput` to update the second dropdownmenu whenever the first one changes

Here is an example for the second option

```
library(shiny)

problemList <- list(
  deeperList = list(
    element1 = 1, element2 = 2),
  deeperList2 = list(
    element3 = 3, element4 = 4)
)

ui <- inputPanel(
  selectInput("category", "choose a category", names(problemList)),
  selectInput("choice", "select a choice", problemList[[1]])
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choice", choices = problemList[[input$category]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Option 2 should be better in most cases, since re-rendering UIs based on inputs can lead to some wierd bugs and bad performance.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.